# Java counter + random numbers

Tags: java

I am trying to generate random number, but also I want to count how many times does it take to generate specific number and show random number which was generated.

So far, my code works just how I wanted, but I feel it could be written easier and more precisely, since I need to set random number range twice.

```
    Random r = new Random();
    int x = r.nextInt(50)+1;
    int o = 0;
    
    while(x!=15) {
        o++;
        System.out.println("Try number: " + o + " and random number is: " + x);
        x = r.nextInt(50)+1;
    }
    
    System.out.println("The answer is 15!");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could eliminate the redundant assignment by changing from a `while` loop to a `do-while` loop. Like,

```
int x;
int o = 0;
do {
    x = r.nextInt(50) + 1;
    System.out.println("Try number: " + o + " and random number is: " + x);
    o++;
} while (x != 15);
System.out.println("The answer is 15!");
```

Answer (score 0):

I made your code look shorter but it actually loses readability.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class ReandomInt {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random r = new Random();
        int x;
        int o = 0;
        
        while(( x = r.nextInt(50)+1)!=15) {        
            System.out.println("Try number: " + (++o) + " and random number is: " + x);
        }
        
        System.out.println("The answer is 15!");
    }

}
```